# Get value from select and compare with the DB to obtain a price

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, mysqli

I'm using a select to choose from different products, then with that value I perform a DB query consult to obtain the price of the product and then set a input tag with it.

```
<section id="products">
        quantity: <input type="number" id="quantity"><br><br>
        <section id="selectProd">
                <?php
                $query = $conn->query("SELECT name FROM Products ORDER BY name"); 
                ?>
                Product: <select id="comProduct" class="comProduct">
                    <?php while ($option = $query->fetch_object()) { ?>
                        <option><?php echo $option->name; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
                <script>
                   $(document).on("ready",function(){
                     $("#comProduct").on("click", function(){

                      var value = $("#comProduct option:selected").text();
                      <?php
                      $servername = "localhost";
                      $username = "root";
                      $password = "";
                      $database = "BERAKA";
                      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
                      if ($conn->connect_error) {
                         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                      }
                     $valuephp = $_GET['value'];
                     $query = $conn->query("SELECT price FROM products where name='$valorphp'");
                     ?>

                     document.getElementById("ppu").value = "<?php $query->fetch_object(); ?>";
                   });
                  });     
               </script>
       </section> <br>
       Price per unit: <input type="text" id="ppu" >
   </section>
```

Don't know why it's not working, Please help

Comment: does it give errors?

Comment: You shouldn't be injecting PHP/SQL inside JS like that.

Comment: You should consider using AJAX if you want to do it that way. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Comment: where `$valorphp` comes from? I think as caCtus mentioned, you need to use ajax.

Comment: I've never used ajax before, i'm just a begginer at web develop

Answer (score 1):

You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Sit back and relax - your problem will become moot when your server gets pwn3d.

As well, your code is highly flawed:

```
document.getElementById("ppu").value = "<?php $query->fetch_object(); ?>";
```

Your fetch call doesn't **DO** anything useful. fetch will RETURN an object, but since you don't capture that object or output it in any way, the DB row data will simply be lost. Even if the fetch call DID by some miracle do output, you can't just dump a PHP object into a Javascsript code context.

You need something more like this:

```
<?php 
    ...
    $row = $query->fetch_object();
    $price = $row->price;
?>
    document.getElementById('ppu').value = <?php echo json_encode($price); ?>;
```

Never **EVER** dump text from PHP directly into a JS context without using `json_encode()`. You're at risk of dumping invalid text into the JS code block, which will trigger a JS syntax error, and kill the entire `<script>` block that this bad code is in. Always use json_encode() so that no matter what you're dumping into the JS code, that value will be VALID javascript.